# brew install gcc /Mac OS 10.9 Mavericks

Tags: macos, installation, homebrew, gcc

I'm doing a clean install of Mavericks, and accidentally did

```
brew install gcc
```

which is taking over half an hour, maybe more. Should I terminate it? I know now that I should have installed a specific gcc (maybe gcc48) but it's too late and my macbook air is breathing hard.

Currently done downloading al dependencies, but stuck on the "Installing gcc" part. It's downloaded a gcc-4.9.1.tar.bz2, configured and built it, and is stuck on making the bootstrap.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answered by the people at stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24966404

Summary.

gcc takes a long time to build, over 45 mins, unless you install command line tools and grab a precompiled, bottled version. Terminating brew with Ctrl-C is safe, and brew will not symlink to /usr/local/* until it has finished installing, so you don't have to worry about the extra stuff. Finally, the point of getting gcc was getting gfortran for scipy, but avoiding common problems in `pip install` and getting scipy can also be done with the [homebrew-python tap](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-python).